# Using Haskell to remove tautologies from a formula

Tags: haskell

Ok so I divided my huge problem set into small parts, and I'm trying to do them one at a time.

I'm writting a function that will remove tautologies from a formula.The basic idea is that if in a clause, a literal and its negation are found, it means that the clause will be true, regardless of the value finally assigned to that propositional variable.My appoach is to create a function that will remove this but for a clause and map it to the formula. Of course, I have to remove duplicates at the beginning.

```
module Algorithm where

import System.Random
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List

type Atom = String
type Literal = (Bool,Atom)
type Clause = [Literal]
type Formula = [Clause]
type Model = [(Atom, Bool)]
type Node = (Formula, ([Atom], Model))
removeTautologies :: Formula -> Formula
removeTautologies = map tC.map head.group.sort
  where rt ((vx, x) : (vy, y) : clauses) | x == y = rt rest
                                      | otherwise = (vx, x) : rt ((vy, y) : clauses)
```

Now I have problems  when I try to give it a formula (for example (A v B v -A) ^ (B v C v A)).Considering that example the first clause contains the literals A and -A. This means that the clause will always be true, in which case it can be simplify the whole set to simply (B v C v A) . But I get the following

```
Loading package old-locale-1.0.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package time-1.1.4 ... linking ... done.
Loading package random-1.0.0.2 ... linking ... done.
[[(True,"A"),(True,"B")*** Exception: Algorithm.hs:(165,11)-(166,83): Non-exhaustive patterns in function rt
```

What should I do?

Comment: You just changed the existing question. I meant for you to press the "Ask Question" button on the top right and create a *new* question. That will get it on the front page and get other people to help you too. Also, my answer won't look out of place :) Just make sure you include your changed code in that new question, and show examples of inputs and outputs that the function is producing, and what you were expecting. You can find other tips for asking good questions [here](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about what happens when you pass `[(True,"A"),(True,"B"),(False,"A")]` to the `rt` function:

```
rt [(True,"A"),(True,"B"),(False,"A")] =
  = rt ((True,"A"):(True,"B"):[(False,"A")] =
    -- (vx,x) = (True,"A"), (vy,y) = (True,"B"), clauses = [(False, "A")]
  = (True, "A") : rt ((True,"B"):[(False, "A")] =
    -- (vx,x) = (True,"B"), (vy,y) = (False,"A"), clauses = []
  = (True, "A") : (True,"B") : rt (False, "A"):[] =
    -- (vx,x) = (True,"B"), (vy,y) = ???
```

In your recursive invocations you are gradually passing shorter and shorter lists to `rt`. But you don't have an equation to deal with lists with less than one element!

You need to had such an equation. Think about what should `rt [(False, "A")]` return. I think the correct answer would be to simply return `[(False, "A")]` unchanged:

```
rt [(vx,x)] = [(vx,x)]
```

Now, are you considering the possibility of having empty formulas?
"Nah, an empty formula makes no sense!"

Well, think about the formula (A ∨ ¬A). It is a tautology. If you remove it you're left with an empty formula! So, an empty formula does make some sense. It is the most basic tautology.

What happens if we pass an empty formula to `rt`? Again, there is no equation for `rt []`. In this case, you cannot remove anything else. You'll have to return it untouched, just like before:

```
rt [] = []
```

If you want you can combine these two extra equations into a single one:

```
rt ((vx, x) : (vy, y) : clauses) | -- ... blah blah
                                 | -- ... blah blah
rt x = x
```

Comment: no I have a another problem ,what should I add for the function rt?

Comment: @TKFALS: Hope that helps. I haven't had the opportunity to test anything yet (no Haskell interpreter here :(, but I think that should solve your problem.

Comment: thank you it does but now the funtion returns exaclty the input:(((

Comment: @TKFALS: That's because you're only checking for consecutive duplicates. Try `[(True,"A"),(False,"A"),(False,"B")]`. It should give `[(False,"B")]`. Then try `[(True,"A"),(True,"A"),(False,"B")]`. It will probably give `[(False,"B")]`, but it should give ``[(True,"A"),(True,"A"),(False,"B")]`` or `[(True,"A"),(False,"B")]`. You'll have to work that out. If you have some more difficulties, it might be better to open a new question for that.